# Redirecting all sub pages to another subpage using htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I've a older site running in Apache Server which is already indexed in Google. I wish to redirect all those indexed links to my new site (As the older pages are not existing any more.)

So i wish to redirect all my sub-sub pages to my new root page

I've pages like follows

```
http://itdost.com/answer-now/Aerobics
http://itdost.com/answer-now/HTML
http://itdost.com/answer-now/Culture
```

I use the following redirect code for each one

```
Redirect 301 /answer-now/Engineering http://www.itdost.com/questions/
Redirect 301 /answer-now/Food http://www.itdost.com/questions/
Redirect 301 /answer-now/ASP http://www.itdost.com/questions/
```

But as the site structure is big, i wish to do it in a single line instead of writing a line for each redirect

Some thing like the following.

```
Redirect 301 /answer-now/% http://www.itdost.com/questions/
```

But the above code does not seems to work

Comment: Do you want to redirect all the different `/answer-now/...` pages to a single `/questions/` page or does each old page have its own corresponding new page?

Comment: 1st option is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you want to redirect all your old pages to a single new page, that following configuration directive should be all you need:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /answer-now/.* http://www.itdost.com/questions
```

See apache [RedirectMatch directive docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) for more info.

The `Redirect` directive, will always append the end of the old URL to the new one.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution just worked like magic. It solved many issues in my website.

Comment: @2lessons Can you also up vote my answer as it seems it did satisfy you?  That usually is [the practice on SE.](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) Thanks!

Comment: Up vote requires 15 reputation, still waiting for it

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive to allow wild-carding like this.

Comment: meulop is correct that you need to use `RedirectMatch` if you want to use wildcards, but in this case no wildcard is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, but you don't need a `%` in the `Redirect` statement.

`Redirect 301 /answer-now http://www.itdost.com/questions`

This will catch all of the queries rooted under `/answer-now`, [per the example in the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

Comment: I've tried the above. It solves my purpose partially. Because it will only redirect http://www.itdost.com/answer-now to http://www.itdost.com/questions. But i wish all the sub-pages of http://www.itdost.com/answer-now. e.g. http://www.itdost.com/answer-now/Foods, http://www.itdost.com/answer-now/ASP to be redirected to http://www.itdost.com/questions...

Comment: That doesn't seem correct, because the `Redirect` directive is recursive. `/foo /bar` will redirect `/foo/test` to `/bar/test`, `/foo/test1/test2` to `/bar/test1/test2`, etc. In your example, you had an unnecessary `%` character that would have prevented correct operation.